# Is it possible to install the Google Keyboard on 4.1.1?

Tags: keyboard, htc-desire, htc, gboard

I have a HTC Desire X running 4.1.1. I want to use the google keyboard - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin - but I get a device incompatibility and the playstore doesn't allow me to install it.

I found an APK here - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2312179 - there is a link there to v3.0.19423.1102675a.

I was wondering if there is any harm in trying to install the keyboard through the APK - anyone tried it. Keyboards are the first thing you use to interact with the system - so I am worried if something goes wrong, I may not even be able to uninstall it or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My phone is working on 4.1.1 and I downloaded and installed the application, it worked fine. No problems at all. XDA seems to be a reliable source. I used it to type this answer and I'm going to uninstall it as I have paid version of SwiftKey.

I'll post a comment whether it uninstalls or not.

Comment: It's very easy to uninstall the application. Just like any other app, go into application manager and uninstall it. But I must say, the keyboard was quicker than SwiftKey and also consumes much less RAM(30-40 MB on SwiftKey vs 16 MB on Google keyboard). I'm going to reinstall it.(from xda)

Comment: BTW, SwiftKey is now free. I just installed it today - I am wondering now whether to keep it or to try the Google Keyboard APK from XDA.

Comment: Sorry! I meant I have paid themes :P